# Uber/Fat jar created by maven plugin causing issue with tibco jars

Tags: java, maven

We already have uber jar for spring application and working fine. Recently we added below dependencies to built messaging functionality:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.tibco.tibrv</groupId>
            <artifactId>tibco-tibjms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tibco.tibrv</groupId>
            <artifactId>tibco-tibcrypt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

After building and running using maven shade plugin we are getting below error:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile
```

If i try to open jar manually it shows below error:

```
•Invalid file name changed to: com/tibco/security/dyn/oOOO/oOoO(1).class (1,010)
•Invalid file name changed to: com/tibco/security/dyn/oOOO/ooOO(2).class (1,010)
•Invalid file name changed to: com/tibco/security/principals/MyHashMap$_o0(1).class (1,010)
•Invalid file name changed to: com/tibco/security/principals/MyHashMap$_oOo(1).class (1,010)
•Invalid file name changed to: com/tibco/security/principals/MyHashMap$_oo(1).class (1,010)
•Invalid file name changed to: com/tibco/security/ssl/A/oOOO(1).class (1,010)
•Invalid file name changed to: com/tibco/security/ssl/OoOO/oOOO(1).class (1,010)
```

Please assist, we need above dependency tried to move order of dependency but same issue.

Comment: delete .m2 file and clean and instal

Comment: Turn to check the checksums and fail if they are wrong...